# How to find where a special Smarty variable is declared in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, variable-assignment, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, smarty3

I using prestashop 1.6 and I have some variable in my `index.tpl` like as `$aslist` that I **Don't know** where this variable is defined or assigned!
I need to find this variable and do some change over that.
anybody know how can I find a solution that show where smarty variables assigned ?

I need to a address file like as:
`$aslist` assigned in `.\www\controllers\front\CmsController.php - (line 58 )`

Comment: Where this index.tpl is located(directory structure) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this function to `config/config.inc.php`

```
function log_smarty_assign($var_name)
{
    $smarty_var_filter = 'aslist';
    if ($var_name == $smarty_var_filter)
    {
        $log = '';
        $trace = debug_backtrace(false);
        if (isset($trace[1]))
        {
            $log .= 'Variable '.$var_name.' assigned in ';
            $log .= $trace[1]['file'].' #'.$trace[1]['line'];
            echo "<pre>$log</pre>";
        }           
    }
}
```

**Edit:** `$trace[1]` should be used instead of `$trace[2]`

And then search for the smarty `assign` method and modify it to something like this:
I found it in `/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_data.php`

```
public function assign($tpl_var, $value = null, $nocache = false)
{
    if (is_array($tpl_var)) {
        foreach ($tpl_var as $_key => $_val) {
            if ($_key != '') {
                $this->tpl_vars[$_key] = new Smarty_variable($_val, $nocache);
                //log the assignment 
                log_smarty_assign($_key);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($tpl_var != '') {
            $this->tpl_vars[$tpl_var] = new Smarty_variable($value, $nocache);
            //log the assignment 
            log_smarty_assign($tpl_var);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Output example:

```
Variable product assigned in ...\classes\controller\Controller.php #180
```